# smtp connection error when sending mail only on *wired* connection, not wireless

Tags: networking, email, emacs

I'm using smtpmail to send email (via mu4e) in Emacs at my work. When I connect via wireless, I can send mail without problem, but when I connect to the wired connection it doesn't work, producing an error:

```
 network-stream-open-starttls: smtp.gmail.com/587 System error
```

Given that I can access the internet via the wired connection, I'm not sure why the wired connection wouldn't work for sending mail.

Comment: Same network, or different networks?  Some folks/ISPs/businesses block outgoing email ports for security reasons.

Comment: They're both my work's networks.

Answer (score 2):

As BrianAdkins says, this is probably related to the differing security policies on the two networks.  You say

> I can access the internet via the wired connection

but have you tested specifically whether you can access gmail.com via the wired connection?

My guess is that your company simply does not allow encrypted connections over the wired link to email, social media, or file-sharing sites.  You can test this hypothesis by visiting, say, mail.yahoo.com, facebook.com, or dropbox.com.  They will all probably be rejected on the wired link.

Comment: Yes, I can access the gmail webclient on the wired connection.

Answer (score 2):

when you are on the wired connection, go to a Command Prompt and type the following:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

If you see something like this below, then port 587 is open on the wired connection...

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP ct4sm32676792pbb.41 - gsmtp
```

If you just see, the following for a minute, then that port is blocked.

```
Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...
```

If the port is blocked, then you will not be able to send e-mail via smtp.gmail.com

[Google always sending e-mail on other ports](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en), but you have to re-configure your e-mail client...

Comment: So far I'm not seeing either.  I see:
     Trying 173.194.77.108...
for a couple of minutes, and then:
      Trying 173.194.77.109...  [I also get the same when I try ports 465 or 25 ?!]
I'm assuming that means that port is blocked?

Comment: Yes, the ports are likely blocked. I know our work blocks the common ports for outgoing e-mail because they want all e-mail sent through a central server. This prevents virus/trojan/worms that may try to send out spam.

Comment: @SunWKim So then would you say that BeSlayed's company has just made an oversight in allowing their wireless network devices to make this external SMTP connection?  (In my experience, a company's wireless network has had a separate security policy from the wired network if and only if company devices cannot access the wireless network -- e.g., if the wireless is for cell phones or visitors only.  But that does not seem to be the case for BeSlayed.)

Comment: @dg99 depends on the company policy. We have WiFi access that lets the company laptop access and we can send e-mail from there if we want. The WiFi is open to all visitors and MAC addresses are not checked to see if they belong to the company.

Comment: @dg99  There is an open (guest) WiFi, but I'm connecting to password-protected WiFi.

Comment: @BeSlayed perhaps you feel a password-protected WiFi may give you more access, but I tend to think it is not relevant.

Comment: The wired connection is faster than the password-protected WiFi. The password protected WiFi is faster than the guest WiFi. I just want to use the fastest connection, but the problem described here is preventing me from being able to use the wired line.

Comment: @BeSlayed Talk to your network admin at work. Your comments at this point are diverging from the original question about why you can't send e-mail from specific networks. Speed was not a consideration earlier and I don't think its relevant... other than you wanting to use the fastest network. ;)